# Webview in Facebook Messenger returns user id after Button Template, but not after persistant menu button

Tags: facebook, webview, menu, sdk

When I generate this template, I'll get the user id in the webview:

```js
{
  "message" : {
      "attachment" : {
          "type" : "template", 
          "payload" : {
              "template_type" : "button", 
              "text" : "webview test", 
              "buttons" : [
                  {
                      "type" : "web_url", 
                      "url" : "...", 
                      "title" : "open", 
                      "webview_height_ratio" : "full", 
                      "messenger_extensions" : true
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  }
}
```

But when I try to access the same webview via a persistant menu, I get an error: This SDK method is not supported on this Messenger client. Please Upgrade.

I've posted this to the Facebook Api to set the menu:

```js
{
  "persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "composer_input_disabled":false,
      "call_to_actions":[
         {
           "type":"web_url",
           "title":"Instellingen",
           "url":"###URL###",
           "webview_height_ratio":"full",
           "messenger_extensions": true
         }
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The menu is displayed properly in the Messenger App (mobile).
I also have the latest version of the Messenger App installed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?